# Correct way to handle JPMS modules and compatiblity with java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I have an app that runs correctly on java 8 but should be compatible with java 9+ (including 17), those complain that some modules are not open like native plaf packages (system look and feel)

So far here is what I've got:

- `java --add-exports -cp libs/* ...` works but not desirable solution
- `java -cp libs/* ...` +  Manifest's Add-Exports in the jar that uses the system plaf, does not work

My question is: what is the correct way to do in the a long term? making my app jars modular?

Comment: Manifest `Add-Exports` only works if you use `java -jar`. The good news: You specify the class-path in the manifest as well.

Comment: The correct way in the long term is to not rely on internals. Using `--add-exports` can only work mid or even short term, depending on how soon the JDK developers will have a reason to change those internals the first time.